# Передать событие приватного поля во внешнюю среду

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, класс в себе инкапсулирует некоторый тип, который хранится в приватном поле.

У этого типа есть некоторое событие и хотелось бы, что бы из вне на это событие можно было подписаться.

Подскажите, единственный вариант решения- это создать публичное событие, затем подписаться внутри класса на событие приватного поля, и уже вызывать публичное событие в обработчике или есть какой-то особенный синтаксис?

Answer (score 2):

Создайте своё публичное событие, в его реализациях add и remove подписывайте подписчика напрямую с событию приватного объекта:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
        myTimer.Tick += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MyTimer
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000);

    public MyTimer()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    public event ElapsedEventHandler Tick
    {
        add => timer.Elapsed += value;
        remove => timer.Elapsed -= value;
    }
}
```

---

Если сильно захотеть - можно развернуть идею до чего-то такого, теперь приватный объект не "утечет", да и сигнатуру события можно подменить:

```
class MyTimer
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(333);

    public MyTimer()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    Dictionary<ElapsedEventHandler, Action> handlers
        = new Dictionary<ElapsedEventHandler, Action>();

    public event Action Tick
    {
        add
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            ElapsedEventHandler h = (o, e) => value.Invoke();
            handlers[h] = value;
            timer.Elapsed += h;
        }
        remove
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            ElapsedEventHandler h = handlers.FirstOrDefault(
                                      pair => pair.Value == value).Key;
            if (h == null) return;
            timer.Elapsed -= h;
            handlers.Remove(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что ключ и значение в словаре местами менять нельзя, иначе при повторной подписке одного и того же метода вы не сможете потом отписаться от созданной лямбды (потому что каждый раз лямбда превращается в новый метод, который перезапишет в словаре предыдущий, так как ключ у них будет одинаковый)

Протестировать можно таким кодом:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();
        myTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick1;
        Console.ReadLine();
        myTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick2;
        Console.ReadLine();
        myTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick2;
        Console.ReadLine();
        myTimer.Tick -= MyTimer_Tick2;
        Console.ReadLine();
        myTimer.Tick -= MyTimer_Tick2;
        Console.ReadLine();
        myTimer.Tick -= MyTimer_Tick2;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void MyTimer_Tick2() => Console.WriteLine(2);

    private static void MyTimer_Tick1() => Console.WriteLine(1);
}
```

Повторные подписки и отписки работают корректно, также отписка неподписанного метода не бросает исключений.

Если еще немного извратиться, может быть даже можно будет сообразить дженерик-класс для конвертации разных делегатов, который инкапсулирует в себе словарь и всю грязную работу, но, по мне, это уже через чур

---

Интерес взял-таки своё, набросал класс, но почему-то отписка не работает, может кто в комментариях подскажет как починить...

```
class DelegateConverter<TIn, TOut> where TIn  : class
                                   where TOut : class
{
    Dictionary<TOut, TIn> handlers = new Dictionary<TOut, TIn>();

    Func<TIn, TOut> _convertFunc;

    public DelegateConverter(Func<TIn, TOut> convertFunc)
    {
        _convertFunc = convertFunc;
    }

    public TOut Add(TIn d)
    {
        if (d == null) return null;
        TOut h = _convertFunc(d);
        handlers[h] = d;
        return h;
    }

    public TOut Remove(TIn d)
    {
        if (d == null) return null;
        TOut h = null;
        foreach (var pair in handlers)
            if (pair.Value == d) h = pair.Key;
        //TOut h = handlers.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Value == d).Key;
        if (h == null) return null;
        handlers.Remove(h);
        return h;
    }
}
```

Здесь в методе `Remove` почему-то всегда `h == null`...

Переписанный метод нашего `MyTimer`:

```
class MyTimer
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(333);

    public MyTimer()
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    DelegateConverter<Action, ElapsedEventHandler> dConverter
        = new DelegateConverter<Action, ElapsedEventHandler>(v => (o, e) => v.Invoke());

    public event Action Tick
    {
        add => timer.Elapsed += dConverter.Add(value);
        remove => timer.Elapsed -= dConverter.Remove(value);
    }
}
```

Тестируем по старому

Comment: Не самое лучшее решение: приватная переменная будет "утекать" в первом аргументе события.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну тогда только подписываться и перевозбуждать. Здесь минус еще в том, что изменить тип делегата непонятно как, чтобы потом можно было и безболезненно отписаться...

Comment: мне кажется, или по сравнению с классической маршрутизацией события через внутренний обработчик, кода стало больше, а надежность меньше? Ну и вопрос про поломавшуюся отписку вопрос по хорошему нужно отдельно оформить.

Comment: @rdorn, конечно, классический вариант проще и надёжнее и я предпочел бы именно его. Но раз уж автор спрашивает... Так сказать, в качестве факультативного задания, почему бы и не развлечься?

Comment: Попробуйте с двумя симметричными словарями. Последний раз я двусторонний конвертер делал именно так, получилось довольно надежно и эффективно.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно сохранить приватность внутреннего экземпляра, то да, единственный надежный способ - создание независимого внешнего события и возбуждение его в обработчике внутреннего. Разумеется можно придумать ряд экзотических вариантов и героически решать возникающие проблемы, только вот количество кода это не уменьшит, а надежность может серьезно пострадать.

У этого способа есть и другие достоинства:

- Вы не обязаны использовать делегат того же типа, который был у первичного источника события. Это дает некоторую дополнительную гибкость в передаче необходимых параметров внешним обработчикам.
- Также не вызывает проблемы добавить приватную логику обработки исходного события. Такое нужно, например, в WinForms, для нисходящей маршрутизации событий (от дочерних контролов к родительскому). Конечно это может и не потребоваться ни сразу, ни позже, но зачем собственноручно закладывать мину замедленного действия и ждать рванет или нет.

---

Если сохранять приватность не обязательно (т.е. наш код не имеет жесткой зависимости от состояния внутреннего объекта):

- Можно использовать решение из соседнего ответа (в первой редакции). Стандартные делегаты событий первым параметром принимают ссылку на объект, возбудивший событие, и по этой ссылке можно получить доступ к самому объекту, поэтому этот вариант позволяет спокойно обойти приватность объекта источника.
- Мне больше нравиться просто заменить поле на публичное свойство только для чтения, раз уж приватность не важна, и подписываться напрямую.

Comment: Выносить приватное поле на публику тоже может быть не хорошо, кроме подписки на событие, внешний код может вызвать метод этого объекта или ещё как-то изменить его внутреннее состояние, что в свою очередь может сломать логику вашего класса... Так что лучше уж пробросить событие

Comment: @Андрей Я специально уточнил, что это на случай, когда приватность значения не имеет, а это уже подразумевает неограниченный доступ. Такое бывает нужно довольно редко, но если нужно, то по мне лучше так.

Comment: @Андрей теперь вроде разночтений быть не должно